# .bashrc running an alias without my approval: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: macos, ubuntu, bash, git, .bash-profile

I have this in bash_profile, I've narrowed the culprit to:

```
alias initialpush="git push -u origin `git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD`"
```

I cannot properly source bash_profile:

```
cchilders:~ 
$ src
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Changing to other style doesn't help, same issue:

```
alias initialpush="git push -u origin $(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)"
```

I think this is only happening on Mac, I can't be sure till I go home and check. My scripts were written on Ubuntu. I don't remember this error happening till I got a Mac at work. How can I stop this bash_profile from going nuts? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific subcommand style doesn't make any difference – either way, as long as they're within double quotes, they'll be expanded *at the time the 'alias' line is interpreted*. To avoid that, either put the alias command in single quotes, or at least backslash-escape the `$` or `` ` `` symbols.

`alias initialpush='git push -u origin $(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)'`